# How can I convert a matrix of 3d experimental data into a 3d list which can be interpolated in a f(x,y) function

Tags: import, interpolation, list-manipulation

I have a 3d experimental *.txt data with the form:
[image: 3d experimental .txt data format]
    y1         y2         y3
x1  f(x1,y1)   f(x1,y2)   f(x1,y3)
x2  f(x2,y1)   f(x2,y2)   f(x2,y3)
x3  f(x3,y1)   f(x3,y2)   f(x3,y3)

I need to convert that data into a list as argument for the Interpolation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file that looks like:

[image]

```
data = ToExpression[Import["data.txt", "Table"]]
  (* {{y1, y2, y3}, {x1, f[x1, y1], f[x1, y2], f[x1, y3]}, {x2, f[x2, y1], 
     f[x2, y2], f[x2, y3]}, {x3, f[x3, y1], f[x3, y2], f[x3, y3]}} *)

ys = data[[1]]
  (* {y1, y2, y3} *)

xs = data[[2 ;;, 1]]
  (* {x1, x2, x3} *)

fs = data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
  (* {{f[x1, y1], f[x1, y2], f[x1, y3]}, {f[x2, y1], f[x2, y2], 
     f[x2, y3]}, {f[x3, y1], f[x3, y2], f[x3, y3]}} *)

xyzdata = 
 Flatten[Table[{xs[[j]], ys[[i]], fs[[j, i]]}, {j, Length[xs]}, {i, Length[ys]}], 1]

  (* {{x1, y1, f[x1, y1]}, {x1, y2, f[x1, y2]}, {x1, y3, f[x1, y3]}, 
      {x2, y1, f[x2, y1]}, {x2, y2, f[x2, y2]}, {x2, y3, f[x2, y3]}, 
      {x3, y1, f[x3, y1]}, {x3, y2, f[x3, y2]}, {x3, y3, f[x3, y3]}} *)
```

Or alternatively

```
indices = Tuples[{Range[Length[xs]], Range[Length[ys]]}];
xyzdata = {xs[[#[[1]]]], ys[[#[[2]]]], fs[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]} & /@ indices

  (* {{x1, y1, f[x1, y1]}, {x1, y2, f[x1, y2]}, {x1, y3, f[x1, y3]}, 
      {x2, y1, f[x2, y1]}, {x2, y2, f[x2, y2]}, {x2, y3, f[x2, y3]}, 
      {x3, y1, f[x3, y1]}, {x3, y2, f[x3, y2]}, {x3, y3, f[x3, y3]}} *)
```

Or all in one step, though I usually prefer a less confusing approach:

```
xyzdata = Flatten[Table[{data[[1 + j, 1]], data[[1, i]], 
   data[[1 + j, 1 + i]]}, {j, Length[data] - 1}, {i, 
   Length[data[[1]]]}], 1]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

First just get the data into Mathematica correctly formatted.  You have a 2D matrix of data so read it that way.  Here's an example:  I entered the following data into Notepad and saved it as (space delimited) a txt file:

1 1 1 1

2 2 4 8

3 3 9 27

Now read it into a 2D table:

```
myFunctionName = NotebookDirectory[] <> "myData.txt";
ReadList[myFunctionName, Number, RecordLists -> True]
```

{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 8}, {3, 3, 9, 27}}

Note:  you will have to save the nb file with this code in the same directory as the txt file before you execute the code.

Comment: Thank you very much!